# Python ConfigParser Name

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python ConfigParser Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10654461/python-configparser-question)

Does the Config file for the ConfigParser have to be named "Config.ini" in order to work?

I want the name to be "1Config.ini" so that it appears at the top of a folder dir.

This is what I have currently

```
config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
config.read(Revision[0:Revision.rfind('\\')] + "\1Config.ini")
Type = config.get("myvars", "Type")
```

I get this error however when the file and code is named "1Config.ini"

```
<class 'ConfigParser.NoSectionError'>: No section: 'myvars'
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape your backslash: `"\\1Config.ini"`

What's happening is that the parser is interpreting the \1 as an octal constant for the character with character code 1.

Another option would be to make that a raw string: `r"\1Config.ini"`