# Python ConfigParser Question

Tags: arcgis, python

Does the Config file for the ConfigParser have to be named "Config.ini" in order to work?

I want the name to be "1Config.ini" so that it appears at the top of a folder dir.

This is what I have currently

```
config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
config.read(Revision[0:Revision.rfind('\\')] + "\1Config.ini")

Type = config.get("myvars", "Type")
```

I get this error however when the file and code is named "1Config.ini"

```
<class 'ConfigParser.NoSectionError'>: No section: 'myvars'
```

Comment: You should ask this on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Your right! I actually have both windows open and posted in the wrong one... my bad

Comment: Also seems a bit frivolous to rename config files just to get them to show up at the top. I mean, what if they are sorting by something other than alphabetical, ascending?

Comment: Also you need to escape that backslash or better yet use [`os.path.join`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.join).

Comment: While that error does seem to pop up if the file isn't found, it is saying that your section doesn't exist.  Presumably you've done this, but I'll recommend that you make sure the section is specificed properly (and capitalization counts!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the output of the following? Make sure it's a valid file name.

```
>>> print Revision[0:Revision.rfind('\\')] + "\1Config.ini"
```

Ideally use `os.path.join` instead of concatenating strings:

```
import os
filename = os.path.join(Revision[0:Revision.rfind('\\')], "Config.ini")
config.read(filename)
```

You probably shouldn't name your variable `Type`, because `type` is a built-in function/module and it'd be confusing.

```
Type = config.get("myvars", "Type")
```

And no, config files can be named anything:

```
>>> a = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
>>> a.read("E:/Documents/2012/config.test") # where config.test is the example from the documentation
['E:/Documents/2012/config.test']
>>> a.sections()
['My Section']
>>> a.items(a.sections()[0])
[('foodir', 'frob/whatever'),
 ('dir', 'frob'),
 ('long', 'this value continues\nin the next line')]
```